# get id of object saved in django forms.Form

Tags: python, django

models.py:

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    invoice_issued_on = models.DateField()
```

forms.py:

```
class InvoiceForm(forms.Form):
    invoice_issued_on = forms.DateField(
        input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y'],
        initial=today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"),
        label=mark_safe('Issued on'),
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'placeholder': 'DD/MM/YYYY', 'data-date-format':'DD/MM/YYYY', 'class': 'form-control text-center' })
    )

    def save(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        invoice=Invoice(invoice_issued_on=data['invoice_issued_on'])
        instance=invoice.save()
```

Question:
How do i get the id (database id) of the Invoice object saved in the database? Warning i am not using forms.ModelForm so instance.id doesn't work here. For technical reason i cannot use ModelForm.

Comment: did you tried invoice.id or instance.id?

Comment: it doesnt work in form.Forms, there is no attribute id or pk in the object

Comment: is object getting saved in database?

Comment: yes object is saved in the database

Comment: I'd be interested to know what your "technical reason" is for not using ModelForms, they are usually the better solution.

Comment: for model form it gives id if print instance.id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`invoice.save()` do not return the instance.  You should get `pk` right from the `invoice` variable:

```
def save(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data
    invoice = Invoice(invoice_issued_on=data['invoice_issued_on'])
    invoice.save()
    return invoice  # invoice.pk will contain id of the object
```

BTW, there is much shorter version of object creation:

```
def save(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data
    return Invoice.objects.create(invoice_issued_on=data['invoice_issued_on'])
```